# Unable to view Picklist value in UI(when I'm trying to create a record)

Tags: picklist

I have newly added a picklist value in my developing sandbox .Later I deployed it to QA there , while I'm creating a record I can't find that value. In QA setup , I can find the value as a active value. But while I'm creating a record, that value is not populating.

Why would that be? How can I fix it?

Comment: do you have any record types on this object? did you make those picklist values available for record types? did you deploy record types as well?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely an issue with record types.
Check the record type assignment and also mapping of the picklist values to the record type.

Also, as a rule of thumb, when deploying picklist values, make sure you also extract record types of that object from the source org. This takes care of the mapping on its own and you need not add it again as a post deployment step.